# How to force wget to overwrite an existing file ignoring timestamp?

Tags: wget

I tried '-N' and '--no-clobber' but the only result that I get is to retrieve a new copy of the existing example.exe with number a number added using this synax 'example.exe.1'. This is not what I'd like to get. I just need to download and overwrite the file example.exe in the same folder where I already saved a copy of example.com without that wget verifies if the mine is older or newer respect the on example.exe file already present in my download folder. Do you think is i possible or I need to create a script that delete the example.exe file or maybe something that change his modification date etc?

Answer (score 136):

If you specify the output file using the `-O` option it will overwrite any existing file.

For example:

```bash
wget -O index.html bbc.co.uk
```

Run multiple times. It will keep over-writting on index.html.

Comment: It will also touch the file when it downloads it (including the first time), so the original timestamp of the file will not be retained as it is when not using the `-O` switch.

Answer (score 50):

`wget` doesn't let you overwrite an existing file unless you explicitly name the output file on the command line with option `-O`.

I'm a bit lazy and I don't want to type the output file name on the command line when it is already known from the downloaded file. Therefore, I use curl like this:

```
curl -O http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/fr.utf-8.spl
```

Be careful when downloading files like this from unsafe sites. The above command will write a file named as the connected web site wishes to name it (inside the current directory though). The final name may be hidden through redirections and php scripts or be obfuscated in the URL. You might end up overwriting a file you don't want to overwrite.

And if you ever find a file named `ls` or any other enticing name in the current directory after using `curl` that way, refrain from executing the downloaded file. It may be a trojan downloaded from a rogue or corrupted web site!

Comment: He answers the question :) He says one must use `wget https://url.com -O filename_to_squash.py` -- and what's more, he explains why one should be careful downloading & running executables!

Comment: God save your laziness by using `curl`, plus one.

Answer (score 41):

```
wget --backups=1 google.com
```

renames *original* file with `.1` suffix and writes new file to the intended filename.

Not exactly what was requested, but could be handy in some cases.

Comment: Interestingly, the wget version 1.21.3 on Windows git bash overwrites the file with backups=0; `wget http://google.com -O mysavedfile --backups=0` successfully overwrites mysavedfile in this case. 
Cool, and serves OP's purpose (+ mine too)!

Answer (score 25):

`-c` or `--continue`

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):

> If you use ‘-c’ on a non-empty file, and the server does not support
>   continued downloading, Wget will restart the download from scratch and
>   **overwrite the existing file entirely**.

Comment: servers usually do support continued downloading.

Comment: This is a note if the server does not suport continued downloading and not the default behaviour. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: -c seems like a great idea, but it does not check if the file contents have changed, if you are regularly downloading (aka scripted) a file that is updated over time -c will bite you.

Comment: If the files at both ends match, there is however a message: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.`

Answer (score 5):

I like the -c option.  I started with the man page then the web but I've searched for this several times.  Like if you're relaying a webcam so the image needs to always be named image.jpg.  Seems like it should be more clear in the man page.

I've been using this for a couple years to download things in the background, sometimes combined with "limit-rate = " in my wgetrc file

```
while true
do
wget -c -i url.txt && break
echo "Restarting wget"
sleep 2
done
```

Make a little file called url.txt and paste the file's URL into it.  Set this script up in your path or maybe as an alias and run it.  It keeps retrying the download until there's no error.  Sometimes at the end it gets into a loop displaying

```
 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
 The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.
```

but that's harmless, just ctrl-c it.  I think it's always gotten the file I wanted even if wget runs out of retries or the connection temporarily goes away.  I've downloaded things for days at a time with it.  A CD image on dialup, yes, always with wget.

Comment: **WARNING!** It may be a coincidence that it worked for you. `man wget`: _If you use -c on a non-empty file, **and the server does not support continued downloading**, Wget will restart the download from scratch and overwrite the existing file._ Also: 
_**Beginning with Wget 1.7, if you use -c on a file which is of equal size as the one on the server, Wget will refuse to download the file and print an explanatory message.**_

Answer (score 5):

My use case involves two different URLs, sometimes the second one doesn't exist, but if it DOES exist, I want it to overwrite the first file.

The problem of using `wget -O` is that, when the second file DOESN'T exist, it will overwrite the first file with a BLANK file.

So the only way I could find is with an if statement:

```
--spider checks if a file exists, and returns 0 if it does
--quiet fail quietly, with no output
-nv is quiet, but still reports errors

wget -nv https://example.com/files/file01.png -O file01.png
# quietly check if a different version exists
wget --quiet --spider https://example.com/custom-files/file01.png
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then    
    # A different version exists, so download and overwrite the first
    wget -nv https://example.com/custom-files/file01.png -O file01.png
fi
```

It's verbose, but I found it necessary. I hope this is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to get it done with parameter trimming

```
url=https://example.com/example.exe ; wget -nv $url -O ${url##*/}
```

Or you can use basename

```
url=https://example.com/example.exe ; wget -nv $url -O $( basename $url )
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not want to use `-O` and want to specify the output directory only, the following command can be used.

```
wget \
    --directory-prefix "$dest" \
    --backups 0 \
    -- "$link"
```

Answer (score 0):

the first command will download from the source with the wget command
the second command will remove the older file

```
wget \
    --directory-prefix "$dest" \
    --backups 0 \
    -- "$link"; \
    rm '$file.1' -f;
```